# Possible to install 32-bit LXC container in 64-bit host with multilib support?

Tags: 64bit, lxc, 32bit

Is it possible to run a 32-bit LXC container (i.e. x86_32-based) on a 64-bit host (i.e. x86_64-based)?

1. Does it work at all?
2. What precautions may I have to take to make this work?

My kernel would be a 3.19 or newer.

Answer (score 2):

Using Ubuntu `Trusty 14.04`, kernel: `4.2.0-36-generic #42~14.04.1-Ubuntu`, lxc: `1.0.8-0ubuntu0.3` I was able to run a 32bit container in 64bit host.

Running the following cmd: `lxc-create -n test -t /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-download`

Giving these answers:

```
Distribution:  ubuntu
Release: trusty
Architecture: i386
```

The config diff is very minimal: `lxc.arch = x86` vs `lxc.arch = x86_64`

Then simply starting it per usual: `lxc-start -n test`

Confirmed the OS thought the arch was 32bit

```
root@host:~# uname -a
Linux host 4.2.0-36-generic #42~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 13 17:27:22 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@host:~# lxc-attach -n test
groups: cannot find name for group ID 111
root@container:~# uname -a
Linux distro 4.2.0-36-generic #42~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 13 17:27:22 UTC 2016 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I think the groups warning is something in my setup, either way it works!

There is a note in the [Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC) to use linux32 to emulate 32bit. I don't think its needed.

> linux32 lxc-create -n myvm -t debian-wheezy

Comment: for lxd: `lxc launch images:debian/buster/i386`